# What Assert.AreEqual(true, true); does?

Tags: automated-testing, nunit

Can any one explain `Assert.AreEqual(true, true);` with proper example and explanation?

Comment: Why you do you want to assert true is equal to true, is this a trick question? Maybe explain your use case in a bit more detail. Did you find this somewhere?

Comment: Can someone be brave enough to justify downvoting?

Comment: @dzieciou A downvote I believe is automatic when someone issues a vote to close.

Comment: @corsiKa, I have just voted to close and it did not get downvoted.

Comment: I know there is an automatic downvote that occurs in some cases. It could be that it only occurs through the review screen? I don't remember exactly but it can happen automagically.

Comment: I down voted, there's no detail or context to the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Assertions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28software_development%29) to verify something is in a certain state. 
Normally you compare the actual against the excepted state.

Example usage:

- Do some steps in your application
- Gather the value of a field
- Assert that the value is indeed the value you expect

  Assert.AreEqual(Actual, Expected)

This could give an assertion failure if Actual and Expected differ.
During a test run you should not have any assertion failures. :)

Asserts are often used in unit-tests and automated integration tests to give feedback or actually test something during a test run.

Answer (score 2):

> Can any one explain Assert.AreEqual(true, true)

Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if the objects are not equal. Displays a message if the assertion fails.

> example and explanation?

Very simple NUnit test:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SampleUnitTest
{
  [TestFixture]
  public Class SampleTest
  {
    [Test]
    public void AddingOneAndOneResultsInTwo()
    {
      int two = 1 + 1;

      Assert.AreEqual(2, two);
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation is simple too, integer value `two` equals `2` and then method `Assert.AreEqual(2, two)` compares two values `2` and `two`. That is, two references to the same object would evaluate as being equal; two clones of a same object would evaluate as being different. Unless you overload the Equals() instance method of the class(es) those objects belong to, or the == operator for said class(es).
Also, I suggest you to read official documentation and answers on stackoverflow:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222713/how-does-assert-areequal-compare-two-objects-in-net-unit-tests